# How to get play count of videos in Zune PC software?

Tags: windows, zune, zune-software

How do I find out which videos in the Zune software on my PC, have not been played yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, the Zune software only supports this for music.  I would suggest, however, that you mark a video `watched` by editing it's description, perhaps by adding a mark of some sort or just a plain word.

Right-click the video, select `Edit` and a box appears:

[image]

You can edit it's category, genre, title, release date, and description. You could even create your own genre and name it `watched`.